# HTTP load failed with status 404. Django, media (img, video)

Tags: django

Пытаюсь сделать сайт на джанго, на котором можно будет просматривать видео и изоражения. На моем компе все работает, залил свой проект на pythonanywhere.com, настроил. Все работает, но не прогружаются картинки и видео.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоль браузера пишет:

> HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource
>   .../static/20.webm failed.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кто такой `video_object`? Если это модель, дайте её код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте ресурсы по указанным адресам. 
Load of media resource .../static/20.webm failed.
**../static/20.webm** проверьте данный ресурс, он существует по указанному пути? 
Данный путь относительный, потому проверьте его относительно той странице, на которой вы смотрите видео. **..** - это родительский каталог. Например есть два каталога **/f/f0/page0** и **/f/f1/page1**. Так вот, ссылка в page0 на page1 может быть такой **../f1/page1**

Comment: Путь там абсолютный: http://myproject.pythonanywhere.com/static/20.webm

Answer (score -1):

Поменял "{% static 'index.jpeg' %}" и "{% static video_object.src_webm %}" на 
"media/index.jpeg" и "/media/{% video_object.src_webm %}", перекинул  файлы в media и все заработало

Comment: Очень плохое, очень неправильное и очень кривое решение

Comment: @andreymal учитывая, что скорее всего не верно настроен http сервер - да :)